# Laravel responding with html default page ignoring controller

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm trying to make a custom Auth controller with this code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        //validate the request
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        ]);

        $data = $request->all();

        //create new user
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        //return response
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully created user!'], 201);
    }
}
```

the controller should create a new User entry inside the database, the User Model is Laravel's default one, no change has been made.

In my api.php routes file I have this simple routes setup:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
```

the problem is that when I try to send a POST request to /api/register Laravel responds with the default html page:

[image: Postman response to post request]

what am I doing wrong here? Consider that this should be only the back-end of my app so I don't need to setup any view

Comment: run `php artisan optimize` and `composer dum-autoload` and check

Comment: You can also run `php artisan route:list` to see if the route has been defined correctly.

Comment: the auth route is correctly configured but the problem remains the same

Comment: if you share the error code it will be easier the find the problem

Comment: Can you dd() and check if it passes through register() method before validation?

Comment: the status code is 200, no errors are shown in the console, where should I put dd()?

Comment: public function register(Request $request)
    { 
   dd('im here');
  ...

Comment: ok looks like that if I put dd inside the function at the first line it responds with the dump, but if I put it after the validation it responds with the page shown in the question

Comment: Then i think it's related to "confirm" rule on password. You need to send password_confirm field for it to be validated. Do you do that?

Comment: I'm preatty new to that, if you can show me how, I'll do that

Comment: please share you view also. the form and javascript

Comment: I’have no views setup yet, I am only testing this with a postman request

Comment: okay then can you take an screenshoot of your postman so we could see how you are sending the request it's probably the validation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your register method you have validation. If validation fails, it returns you back with validation errors. So you have an error in your $request fields somewhere.

**Name** should be string, **email** must be a valid email and should be unique, meaning that none of the existing users should have it. For **password** you must have confirmation, and that's where i think the problem is.

You should pass to this GET API route not only 'name', 'email' and 'password', but also 'password_confirmation' field which contains same password as 'password' field. I suggest for you to remove this rule to simplify the request, like this :

```
        //validate the request
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
        ]);
```